# How to fix Typescript generic class when "Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated"

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following code. ColumnSorter is intended to encapsulate a set of sorting functions by their string names, then apply the right sort function to an array.

```
export class ColumnSorter<T> {
    constructor(private map: Map<string, (a: T, b: T) => number>) {
    }
    public sortBy<T>(sortcol: string, items: T[]): void {
        // *** DOES NOT COMPILE:
        items.sort(this.map.get(sortcol));
        // *** DOES NOT COMPILE EITHER:
        let fn: (a: T, b: T) => number = this.map.get(sortcol);
    }
}

// here is an example Quote arrays. Others could be position, account, etc.
// implementing with sort functions for that type.
const quoteFunctionMap: Map<string, (a: Quote, b: Quote) => number> = new Map([
    ['byLastPrice', (q1: Quote, q2: Quote) => {
        return q1.lastPrice - q2.lastPrice;
    }],
    ['bySymbol', (q1: Quote, q2: Quote) => {
        return q1.symbol.localeCompare(q2.symbol);
    }]
]);

let colsort = new ColumnSorter<Quote>(quoteFunctionMap);
let quotes: Quote[] = [new Quote(), new Quote()]; // blank quotes, for compile test
colsort.sortBy("byLastPrice", quotes);
```

The problem is fetching the sort function out of the map. The error message is detailed but isn't enough for me to find the root of the problem. Is there something missing from my code?

```
Argument of type '((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined'.
  Type '(a: T, b: T) => number' is not assignable to type '(a: T, b: T) => number'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
    Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
        'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: What is the Quote class (we need the definitions)?

Comment: @pink just consider it a simple data object, where symbol is string and lastPrice is a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ColumnSorter.sortBy` method should use the `T` generic from the class rather than defining it's own one.

```
export class ColumnSorter<T> {
  constructor(private map: Map<string, (a: T, b: T) => number>) {
  }
  // NOTE: changed from sortBy<T> to just sortBy below!
  public sortBy(sortcol: string, items: T[]): void {
    items.sort(this.map.get(sortcol));
    let fn = this.map.get(sortcol);
    if (!fn) {
      throw new Error(`No sorter exists for ${sortcol}`);
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was simple! But for my full understanding, why does the second line (let fn...) still not compile? Using your class definition, I get `Type '((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(a: T, b: T) => number'.⏎ Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(a: T, b: T) => number'.`

Comment: That's because `map.get` can return undefined. So you will need to throw an error if the function cannot be found using the `sortcol` in the map or something like that

Comment: Updated my answer to include this logic.

Comment: Yes map can returned undefined, but I included that in the reference type. You can remove the type and make it compile (which is what you did, no instance check needed) but now it is not the same type, it is just an any type reference. I monkeyed with it and found that the issue is that `number | undefined` is being interpreted by the compiler as the function return type, not an alternate return type. Putting parentheses around it makes it compile: `let fn: ((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined`

Comment: The type annotation isn't really needed, Typescript already correctly infers it as `((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined` - You can see this by hovering on `fn` here -> https://tsplay.dev/m3BLkN